# How do I add a new key:value pair in existing JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object like:

```
appointerment= {ids: '15,16,17', appointments: {'15': '12.05.2010,14,05,2010'} }
```

now in appointments object I want to add something like `'16': '21.05.2010'`

what is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
appointerment.appointments['16'] = '21.05.2010';
```

JSON is short for "JavaScript Object Notation", and as the name implies, it's basically just a way of representing Javascript objects. Thus, one can interact with JSON in the ways one tends to interact with any other object in Javascript, via the usage of the `.` or `[]` operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
appoiterment['appointments']['16'] = '21.05.2010';
```

Comment: This is wrong. I assume you meant `appoiterment['appointments']['16']`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = { a:1, b:{c:1} }

x.b.d = 1

// x is now { a:1, b:{c:1, d:1} }
```

Note -  But this won't work in the case of numbers like '16'.